# Can't dismiss BS Modal after loading with AJAX

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I have a Bootstrap 4 Modal which I'm loading with Ajax. I just have the outer container on the page:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="note-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-label"></div>
```

The modal contains a form which is loaded with Ajax:

```
$(body).on("click", "#add-note", function () {
    var url = '/add-a-note';
    $('#note-modal').modal();
    $.get(url, function (data) {
        $("#note-modal").html(data);
        CKEDITOR.on("instanceReady", function (event) {
            $('#loading-editor').hide();
        });
    });
});
```

The dialog loads fine, but I can't dismiss it afterwards. I've tried the close button:

```
<a class="close" data-dismiss="modal" data-target="#note-modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></a>
```

I've also tried:

```
$("#note-modal").modal('hide');
```

Which hides the modal but not the backdrop, so I'm stuck with a grey overlay blocking interaction to the page. I don't seem to be able to remove the backdrop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to have been caused by the use of an empty dialog. I added the following to the #note-modal placeholder and dismiss now works (even though it's replaced with Ajax).

```
<div class="modal fade" id="note-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-label">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-label"></h4>
                <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal" data-target="#note-modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
$('#note-modal').modal('toggle');
```